# Does Vishnu love or not love?

Tags: vishnu, bhagavad-gita

In the ninth discourse of the Gita, 29th verse, Vishnu says:

> There is no one whom I hate or love

and then only a few pages later, in the tenth discourse, 1 st verse, Lord Vishnu states:

> Listen to my highest word, which I will tell you, whom I love with desire for your well-being.

How can these both be true? Is this not a contradiction?

Answer (score 8):

In your Question, you have mentioned only 1st part of **Bhagavad Gita 9.29**. Here is the complete Shloka:

> समोऽहं सर्वभूतेषु न मे द्वेष्योऽस्ति न प्रियः।
>
> ये भजन्ति तु मां भक्त्या मयि ते तेषु चाप्यहम्।।9.29।।

And [this](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=9&field_nsutra_value=29&etgb=1) is how Swami Gambirananda translates it:

> I am **impartial** towards all beings; to Me there is none detastable or none dear. **But** those who worship Me with devotion, they exist in Me, and I too exist in them.

This would be more clear from [English Translation Of Sri Shankaracharya's Sanskrit Commentary By Swami Gambirananda](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=9&field_nsutra_value=29&setgb=1&choose=1):

> Aham, I; am samah, impartial, eal; sarva-bhutesu, towards all beings; me, to Me; na asti, there is none; dvesyah, detestable; na, none; priyah, dear.
>
> **I am like fire: As fire does not ward off cold from those who are afar, but removes it from those who apporach, near, similarly I favour the devotees, not others.**
>
> Tu, but; ye, those who approach near, similarly I favour the devotees, not others. Tu, but; ye, those who; bhajanti, worship Me, God; bhaktya, with devotion; te they; exist mayi, in Me-by their very nature; ['Their mind becomes fit for My manifestation, as it has been purified by following the virtuous path.'] they do not exist in Me because of My love, Ca, and; aham, I; api, too; naturally exist tesu, in them, not in others. Thus there is no hatred towards them (the latter). 'Listen to the greatness of devotion to Me:'

So there is no contradiction between 9.29 and 10.1 Shlokas.

Comment: How can one be impartial, yet favour devotees? The definition of being impartial is to consider and treat all equally

Comment: @EvolianMan "Fire does not ward off cold from those who are afar but removes it from those who approaches fire", so do you consider fire being partial here??? If no then, you can understand it very well...

Comment: That is rather tangent from my main issue in the question, which is that Vishnu states he doesn't love or hate anyone, but then later says he loves Arjuna. How can that be true?

Comment: Lord says "I am impartial towards all beings;" like fire is impartial...but fire remove cold from those who approaches it... it's very simple concept... :)